# Combine c:out tag with bean:message

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Supposing that I have a variable that contains a dynamic label how can I achieve something like this (navigation is a request scope attribute):

```
<fmt:message  var='<c:out value="${navigation}"/>'/>
```

Or

```
<bean:message  var='<c:out value="${navigation}"/>'/>
```

Actually until now was handled like this :

```
<%
    String navigation = (String)request.getAttribute("navigation");
%>

<bean:message  var='navigation'/>
```

But this way of doing things was good ten years ago.

Comment: Is the intent really to display it by `${requestScope[navigation]}` or so? Why exactly don't you just use `var="navigation"` and then later on `${navigation}` to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<c:set var="temp"><c:out value="${navigation}"/></c:set>
<fmt:message var='${temp}'/>
```

Are you sure you mean to use `var=` and not `key=` using the `var=` attribute puts the value of the message in a variable named that value, and doesn't output it to the response.

```
<c:set var="temp">something-complex-<c:out value="${navigation}"/></c:set>
<fmt:message key='${temp}'/>
```

Note this could also be written as:

```
<fmt:message key='something-complex-${navigation}'/>
```

Comment: Yes you were right, I was confused about the var/key behavior :)